# js check to see if user has connection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an easy way to check whether or not the user has connection to your website?

See if they don't get a connection error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple service or page on your website and you can send a XmlHttpRequest (XHR) to your site and make sure you receive a valid 200 response.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX request with a specified timeout that checks to see if you get back a valid response (code 200).